# Cannot index array with string "taskDefinitionArn" using JQ

Tags: json, jenkins, jq

```
{
  "taskDefinition": {
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "family": "decac-DSF-FarmB-BGcore-V7KAEEL71QS8",
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresAttributes": [
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
      },
      {
        "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
      },
      {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
      }
    ],
    "cpu": "8192",
    "compatibilities": [
      "EXTERNAL",
      "EC2"
    ],
    "volumes": [],
    "memory": "12480",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [],
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:020627:task-definition/decac-DSF-FarmB-BGcore-V7KAEEL71QS8:640",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "dnsSearchDomains": [],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "BG_CONFIGURATION_SERVER_URL",
            "value": "http://internal-BGDSF-FarmB-pp-int-ALB-1301919556.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
          },
          {
            "name": "ES_IS_ENABLED_SSL",
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "name": "THINKANALYTICS_ENDPOINT",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "USE_HTTPS",
            "value": "false"
          },
          {
            "name": "BG_CONFIG_REFRESH_INTERVAL",
            "value": "10000"
          },
          {
            "name": "DECOUPLE_DCQ_ENABLED",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "name": "ES_SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "LOG_LEVEL",
            "value": "info"
          }
        ],
        "systemControls": [],
        "name": "BG-core-FarmB",
        "links": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "healthCheck": {
          "retries": 10,
          "interval": 60,
          "command": [
            "CMD-SHELL",
            "/opt/app-root/src/readinessodejs.sh"
          ],
          "startPeriod": 15,
          "timeout": 45
        },
        "image": "020627.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/BG-core:DEE.56.03112022-122711",
        "hostname": "BG-core",
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": 3000,
            "hostPort": 0
          }
        ],
        "dnsServers": [],
        "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
        "entryPoint": [
          "sh",
          "-c"
        ],
        "ulimits": [
          {
            "softLimit": 51200,
            "name": "nofile",
            "hardLimit": 51200
          }
        ],
        "memory": 12480,
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "BG-core-FarmB",
            "awslogs-group": "decacDSF-PP-ECSInfra-KHM9B7BK1HDE-ECSLogGroup-Q2KC9BCLGILN",
            "mode": "non-blocking"
          }
        },
        "command": [
          "/bin/sh -c \"/tmp/scripts/run\""
        ],
        "cpu": 8192,
        "volumesFrom": []
      }
    ],
    "revision": 640
  },
  "tags": []
},
```

This has been working earlier by using the below command:

jq 'map(del(.taskDefinitionArn, .revision, .status,.requiresAttributes,.compatibilities))'

But same command started giving the below error now.

jq: error (at :139): Cannot index array with string "taskDefinitionArn"

I am using JQ version 1.5 did something got changed recently ?

why it is getting failed like that can someone help in here ?

Please find the full JSON code and output which i have replicated in following [link](https://jqplay.org/s/po4ikzuaIwI)

Comment: Maybe you want to use `map_values` instead of `map` as the top-level item is an object, not an array.

Comment: We have used only "map" the command which we are using now will delete the existing values in the json scipt but its not happening now

Comment: @pmf i have tried using "map_values" same still same issue...

 jq 'map_values(del(.taskDefinitionArn, .revision, .status,.requiresAttributes,.compatibilities))' test.json > test1.json
jq: error (at test.json:139): Cannot index array with string "taskDefinitionArn"

Comment: For me, both `map_values` and `map` do work (doing different things, though), and with both jq 1.5 as well as jq 1.6 (after replacing the final comma with two closing braces in your sample code). Here's an online [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Mg_0LLB6s9X) using `map` and jq 1.6.

Comment: @pmf i am trying the same on a amazon linux machine as `jq `map(del(.taskDefinitionArn, .revision, .status,.requiresAttributes,.compatibilities))' test.json > test2.json` i am getting error : Jq: error (at :139): Cannot index array with string "taskDefinitionArn"

Comment: As you can see with the demo, the problem is not with your jq filter, the jq version, or the sample data (when corrected the way described in my previous comment).

Comment: Are you sure that you are processing the correct input JSON?

Comment: @knittl please find the following [link](https://jqplay.org/s/po4ikzuaIwI) for the full code and error

Comment: @pmf please find the following [link](https://jqplay.org/s/po4ikzuaIwI) for the full code and error

Comment: Remove the `map()` from you filter.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the question has been updated with a minimal, reproducible example, the answer is straight forward.
The program should be:

```
.taskDefinition |= del(.taskDefinitionArn, .revision, .status, .requiresAttributes, .compatibilities)
```

It reassigns the `taskDefinition` object to itself with all specified properties removed.

The reason why `map` does not work is that map applies its inner filter to all elements of an array. If you pass in an object, the filter will be applied to all *values* of the object.

```bash
$ jq 'map(.)' <<JSON
{
    "abc":1,
    "xyz":2,
    "more":3
}
JSON
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

This will work as long as your object values are objects themselves, but breaks when you have non-object values. `del` can only be applied to inputs of type objects.

Here's the smallest sample input that will break your `map`-based filter:

```json
{
  "object": {},
  "array": []
}
```

Calling `del` on the value of `object` works: `{} | del(.something)`, but calling it on the value of `array` will break: `[] | del(.something)`.